# got some return that mention about this : uploadLimitExceeeded

Tags: youtube-data-api

#youtube-data-api

hello mate, i'm using a youtube data api v3 for a while, and i got this return [uploadLimitExcedeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOZVS.png)

any reason and advice, please ?

origin return : Error: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.". Details: "[{'message': 'The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.', 'domain': 'youtube.video', 'reason': 'uploadLimitExceeded'}]">

i think it was about the quota, but my very own quota is on a safe limit.

Comment: You should learn to read the error messages.

Comment: `'message': 'The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.'`